# Two errors when trying to render icons dynamically with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm slightly baffled on why I'm unable to generate icons dynamically with the way I've setup my React component.

I've tried using both specific imports for each icon and importing them all at once, however, I keep receiving the same error:

RiSave3Fill /> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

and

RiSave3Fill /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.

Here is my Buttons component where I'm trying to dynamically generate the icons for each button.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import './buttons.scss';
// import * as icons from 'react-icons';
import {MdOutlineClose} from 'react-icons/md';
import { BsCameraVideo } from 'react-icons/bs'
import { TbRotate360, TbRotate2, TbRotateClockwise2 } from 'react-icons/tb';
import { RiSave3Fill } from 'react-icons/ri';

function Buttons(props) {
    return(
        <div className="menu__buttons-wrapper">
            {props.buttons.map((button, index) => {
                const BtnIcon = button.icon;
                
                return (
                    <button key={index}>
                        {<BtnIcon />}
                    </button>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Buttons
```

This is the data structure of (props) in the button component

```
{
        type: "buttons",
        buttons: [
            {
                type: "camera",
                icon: "BsCameraVideo"
            },
            {
                type: "rotateCounterClockwise",
                icon: "TbRotate2"
            },
            {
                type: "rotate360",
                icon: "TbRotate360"
            },
            {
                type: "rotateClockwise",
                icon: "TbRotateClockwise2"
            },
            {
                type: "save",
                icon: "RiSave3Fill"
            },
            {
                type: "close",
                icon: "MdOutlineClose"
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: You've imported a bunch of icons, but you never use them

Comment: Could you show how do you pass props to `Button` component?

Comment: @Konrad I've edited the post to simplify it and show the data im using.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use strings like that. React won't know which component you refer to exactly just by a string

Change strings to the actual components reference and import these components in the same file you are creating this object:

```
{
  type: "buttons",
  buttons: [
    {
      type: "camera",
      icon: BsCameraVideo,
    },
    {
      type: "rotateCounterClockwise",
      icon: TbRotate2,
    },
    {
      type: "rotate360",
      icon: TbRotate360,
    },
    {
      type: "rotateClockwise",
      icon: TbRotateClockwise2,
    },
    {
      type: "save",
      icon: RiSave3Fill,
    },
    {
      type: "close",
      icon: MdOutlineClose,
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Ahh completely overlooked this, thank you. Are you saying to create individual components for each icon in the file where this object is coming from. (atm just a testData.js file) and then import them? Is there any way to do this dynamically as the type of button and icon will be changed frequently.

Comment: You don't have to create new components. Just import them

Comment: Hmm okay, I've tried that and having to manually import the components for each icon isn't as dynamic as I'd have liked and importing all icons is a huge payload. Is there a way I could dynamically import only the icons needed based on the icons submitted in that buttons object?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```js
import { RiSave3Fill } from "react-icons/Ri";
import { MdOutlineClose } from 'react-icons/Md';
```

With this:

```js
import { RiSave3Fill } from "react-icons/ri";  // <-- Lowercase ri
import { MdOutlineClose } from 'react-icons/md'; // <-- Lowercase md
```

Follow this pattern for the rest of the imports.

Comment: Weirdly I've always imported them using that first capital letter and have never had any problems (even though I know it's supposed to be lowercase).

When I change them to lowercase I get this error:

[vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 4 errors:
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\react-icons_md.js
error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\react-icons_tb.js